# Create dynamic HTML from an object in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, rich-text-editor

Consider the given scenario.

I have a class with properties that has all the necessary information regarding a page design. For example I know the line spacings, page number format, text to be displayed, text stye and margin etc.

I want to visualize the exact same page and display it on my Angular SPA. I also want to be able to edit the page layout using text editing tools (just like we have in ant text editing software). For example changing the text color, margins, text size etc and reflect it back to original class instance (two way binding to original object to be precise).

I want to know, Do we have any tool or package that serves the given purpose. If not how we can achieve this requirement in a simple yet effective manner.

Comment: I think you need use `<ng-template>`

Comment: I want to have a text editor like screen where I can edit it (style of document color, fornt etc) and the changes done are reflected back to underlying object. This will not be achieved by `<ng-template>` in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to create your class as a component let us say  `contentComponent` in which your class is attached to an HTML file , the HTML file should rely only on data binding and class binding to show content and set the layout of the page , in the other hand create another component `editComponent` that will get access to  `contentComponent`class properties through a service to set and change its properties and hence reflecting on the `contentComponent` view .

Comment: I was also thinking on the same lines. But for this I will have to create controls like font selector, border etc from scratch. Does WYSIWYG  editors like ckeditor provide a way for two way data and class binding as they have inbuilt support for text formatting.